# How do I make mongoose run validators?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, schema

currently I'm able to update passwords to a single character string, even though my schema prohibits this (by requiring a minLength of 7 chars.) I'll post my controller code below and my question is, how can i make mongoose validate, prior to saving.

```
exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
  const allowedUpdates = ["name", "email", "password", "age"];
  const validOp = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update));

  if (!validOp) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: "invalid updates" });
  }

  try {
    const user = req.user;

    updates.forEach((update) => (user[update] = req.body[update]));
    
    await user.save();

    res.send(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err.message);
  }
};
```

User.js (schema, database thingy):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
//const Task = require("../models/Task");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    age: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
      validate(value) {
        if (value < 0) {
          throw new Error("Age must be a postive number");
        }
      },
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate(value) {
        if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
          throw new Error("email is invalid");
        }
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minLength: 7,
      validate(value) {
        if (value.toLowerCase().includes("password")) {
          throw new Error("password must not contain password");
        }
      },
    },
    tokens: [
      {
        token: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    avatar: {
      type: Buffer,
    },
    verify: {
      type: String,
    },
    resetPasswordToken: {
      type: String,
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

userSchema.virtual("posts", {
  ref: "Post",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "author",
});

userSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  const user = this;
  const userObj = user.toObject();

  delete userObj.password;
  delete userObj.tokens;
  delete userObj.avatar;

  return userObj;
};

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  const user = this;
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id.toString() }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({ token });
  await user.save();
  return token;
};

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("unable to login!");
  }
  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!isMatch) {
    throw new Error("unable to login!");
  }

  return user;
};

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (user.isModified("password")) {
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
  }
  next()
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

More info because SO requires more.

Answer (score 1):

The Mongoose docs show that you can set up a callback inside your save function for errors.

[https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#:~:text=Validation%20is%20middleware.,manually%20run%20validation%20using%20doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#:%7E:text=Validation%20is%20middleware.,manually%20run%20validation%20using%20doc).

For reference, this is their example:

```
var schema = new Schema({
name: {
type: String,
required: true
}
});
var Cat = db.model('Cat', schema);

// This cat has no name :(
var cat = new Cat();
cat.save(function(error) {
assert.equal(error.errors['name'].message,
'Path `name` is required.');

error = cat.validateSync();
assert.equal(error.errors['name'].message,
'Path `name` is required.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how that'll help me get validation working?

Comment: What do you mean? When it's doing the save function it should throw an error if some of the mongoose parameters arent met and abort the save. You could also implement something like express-validator so youre not depending on your database to do all the validation. In case youre interested (https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! Unfortunately I'm not getting any error, and it IS saving the data that doesn't meet required standards. I.E. I was able to save a 1 character password even though my schema requires a 7 char password - I'm at a loss as to why this is possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update the post with your User.js model so we can see if there is anything there that may be causing the issue?